# Infinite sums - order of terms

Tags: real-analysis

say we had an infinite sum $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n $ where $ a_n  = \dfrac{1}{2}  +1 + \dfrac{1}{8} + \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{32} + ... $ this is obviously a rearrangment of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^n} $ but does the order of the sum matter? I know by the general theorem that as $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^n} $ converges absolutely then any rearrangement also converges to the same sum - but how would I go to prove that $a_n$ converges WITHOUT using that theorem? e.g. using the root test

also, why is it for some sums - the order matters, while others it does not

Comment: Since every other partial sum is the same for both series, the equality of the sums is easily deduced. If you chose a more complicated rearrangement, it might be necessary to appeal to the theorem.

Comment: Have you looked at the article about the rearrangement theorem?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: The two best reasons to avoid the theorem are 1. you don't understand its proof or the intuition behind it (in which case you should be asking for help with that) or 2. you are interested in more general contexts where the theorem does not apply. In either case, I don't think this question is attacking the problem from the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If a series involves *only* positive (or at least non-negative) terms, then any rearrangement of the series has the same limit in the sum. One way to prove this is to note that if $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, then

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n = \sup_{A \text{ finite}} \sum_{n \in A} a_n$$

---

To prove that this series converges directly, however, note that we can just compute 
\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{32} + \frac{1}{16} + \dots &= \frac{2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{2}{8} + \frac{2}{32} + \frac{1}{32} + \dots \\
&= \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{3}{32} + \dots \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \left(1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \dots \right) \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}} \\
&= 2
\end{align*}
where we've used a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you for your reply (as well as everyone else): However, I'm stuck on trying to use the root test for this - I see your direct proof using another rearrangement, but I'm trying to prove $a_n$ directly from what was given. A hint is given in the problem to consider the root test and even and odd terms separately, but I cannot conjure a general formula for $a_n$